# Which unit testing framework to use for JavaFX application?

Tags: java, unit-testing, user-interface, junit, javafx-8

I have finished writing an API for my application, and wanted to connect a GUI to it. I am programming in Java, so that's why I chose JavaFX as GUI framework. Because I like its design.

But when I started to write unit tests for JavaFX components, I was surprised that JUnit, Mockito, and PowerMockito doesn't work. e.g. I could not suppress constructor of the class that extends `MenuBar` or `BorderPane` etc.

When I googled, I found out that for writing unit tests for the code that uses JavaFX there are some other frameworks needed *(JemmyFX - seems not being updated for a long time, MarvinFX - very new, TestFX - has alpha version yet)* and I realized there are no good or well-documented frameworks there at all. Here I mean that I could not find any related book.

**Could anyone tell me which unit testing framework to use when writing the GUI in JavaFX?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TestFX is without a doubt the best (and only) testing framework for JavaFX applications. The latest version is marked as `4.0.5-alpha` but it's quite usable and helpful. The reason for the `alpha` tags is mostly related to missing Javadocs on classes and some experimental features that were added in the `4.x` series.

There were substantial documentation updates made between `4.0.4-alpha` and `4.0.5-alpha`.